# Atomic operation functions for Linux 32bit and 64bit?

Tags: linux, compare-and-swap

In Windows, atomic operation functions are separated by 32bit and 64bit like this:

- `InterlockedIncrement32`
- `InterlockedIncrement64`

Meanwhile, what functions do the same in Linux? What is the function for doing 64-bit variable for `__sync_sub_and_fetch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
__sync_fetch_and_add(adress,value);
__sync_fetch_and_sub(adress,value);
```

As for my experience, these functions work seamlessly on Linux64_x86

You can find details below

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html